# reproduce Dymola info layer from python script

Tags: python, modelica, dymola

I would like to write a Python script to extract the same information about the inputs and outputs of a Modelica function as shown in the Dymola info layer, e.g. for the sine function:

[image: 4782]

I would like to show a minimal example but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: some functions in Python have comments which are used to generate documentation. ie. `import math` and `print(math.sin.__doc__)` or `help(math.sin)`. But if your functions are not in Python or they don't have special comments then you have to write all information manually.

Comment: The function is written in Modelica, and Dymola is the editor/IDE. Dymola has a Python interface, so theoretically everything that is possible from the Dymola GUI should also be possible from a Python script.

Comment: I don't know Modelica but in many programs documentation is created manually (or generated from source code and manually corrected) and kept in HTML files. And later IDE displays these HTML files, it doesn't generate it dynamically when you select function. SO I would rather look for files with documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dymola generates this information on the fly for the model documentation, but I am not aware of a way to retrieve it.

The `ModelManagement` library (shipped with Dymola and included in the standard license) allows to extract such information from loaded classes.
However, it is a bit painful to use. The problem is that most functions in this library only analyze the exact code of the class - extended classes are not considered. Hence you have to loop over extended classes by yourself.

Below is an example which tries to get all component definitions of a class, including the ones inherited from extended classes. For every component a dict with several properties is returned, which corresponds to the record `ModelManagement.Structure.AST.ComponentAttributes` in Dymola. 
It contains information like the component name, its description, its variability, the presence of the prefixes `input` and `output` etc.

So for your example class `Modelica.Math.sin` inputs and outputs can be identified easily using the dict keys `isOutput` and `isInput`.

But beware that this does not work for input and output connectors of blocks like `Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput` - and a-causal connectors like electric pins. You will have to implement something by yourself to identify those.

The code below simply uses fixed class paths to list all input and output connectors of `Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.Integrator`. Additionally it outputs all its parameters.

```
import pprint
from dymola.dymola_interface import DymolaInterface


def get_extends(dym, c):
    """ return a list with all extended classes (including inherited extends) """

    extends = dym.ExecuteCommand(f'ModelManagement.Structure.AST.ExtendsInClassAttributes("{c}")')

    for e in extends.copy():

        sub_extends = get_extends(dym, e['fullTypeName'])

        # only add sub-extends if they are not already in the list
        for s in sub_extends:
            if not any(s['fullTypeName'] == tmp_e['fullTypeName'] for tmp_e in extends):
                extends.append(s)

    return extends


def get_components(dym, c):
    """ return a list with all components in a class (including inherited ones )"""

    # get components defined in the class itself
    comp = dym.ExecuteCommand(f'ModelManagement.Structure.AST.ComponentsInClassAttributes("{c}")')

    # get components defined in extended classes itself
    for e in get_extends(dym, c):
        comp.extend(dym.ExecuteCommand(
            f'ModelManagement.Structure.AST.ComponentsInClassAttributes("{e["fullTypeName"]}")'))

    return comp


if __name__ == '__main__':

    modelica_class = 'Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.Integrator'

    # get all components in the model
    dymola = DymolaInterface(showwindow=False)
    components = get_components(dymola, modelica_class)
    dymola.close()

    # extract inputs and parameters
    inputs = ['Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput', 'Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.BooleanInput',
              'Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.BooleanInput']

    inputs = [c for c in components if c['fullTypeName'] in inputs]
    parameters = [c for c in components if c['variability'] == 'parameter']

    print('-------- inputs ------------')
    pprint.pprint(inputs)
    print('\n\n-------- parameters ------------')
    pprint.pprint(parameters)
```

Comment: Thank you for this very comprehensive answer! Very helpful, right now I am only looking at functions. Are there plans to enhance / extend ModelManagement?

Comment: I guess not. According to the release notes the last notable changes of this library happened in 2011 with Dymola 7.4 FD01.
To find out if a class is a function you can use `ModelManagement.Structure.AST.GetClassAttributes` and check the key `restricted` of the returned dict.